# Spring Dataflow Stream File Sink - Need to write to separate files

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have been working with **Spring Cloud Dataflow**. I have written a custom *Cloud Stream Processor* application that takes in a specific type of an XML document, and splits it into smaller XML documents.

I was expecting the *Cloud Stream* definition below to write out multiple files. **Instead** when testing with the same file **it sporadically writes some of my smaller XMLs to one file, and sometimes it writes them out to two** (I am thinking this is due to my `fixed-delay` value in the definition below).

I was wondering how I can get my stream to write each XML document to its own file. When I wrote the processor I specifically used `this.processor.output().send(message);` instead of `@SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)`, thinking that would avoid this exact problem.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Dataflow Stream Definition:**

```java
    xmlSplit=fileIn: file --directory=/root/file_in --filename-regex=redactApplication.xml --fixed-delay=30 --markers-json=false --mode=contents | custom-xml-splitter | fileOut: file --directory=/root/file_out --name-expression="'test' + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMddHHmmss').format(new java.util.Date()) + '.txt'"
```

**Code for my custom processor:**

```java
    @Component
    @EnableBinding(Processor.class)
    public class REDACTXMLSplitter {

        @Autowired
        private Processor processor;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
        public void parseForREDACTApplications(byte[] redcactXMLByteArray) {
            String redcactXML = new String(redcactXMLByteArray);
            InputSource doc = new InputSource( new StringReader( redcactXML ) );
            try
             {

                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    factory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!

                    XPathFactory xfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
                    XPath xpath = xfactory.newXPath();

                    String xpathQuery = "//REDACT/Application";

                    xpath = xfactory.newXPath();
                    XPathExpression query = xpath.compile(xpathQuery);
                    NodeList productNodesFiltered = (NodeList) query.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

                    for (int i=0; i<productNodesFiltered.getLength(); ++i)
                    {

                        Document suppXml = dBuilder.newDocument();

                        //we have to recreate the root node <products>
                        Element root = suppXml.createElement("REDACT"); 

                        Node productNode = productNodesFiltered.item(i);

                        //we append a product (cloned) to the new file
                        Node clonedNode = productNode.cloneNode(true);
                        suppXml.adoptNode(clonedNode); //We adopt the orphan :)
                        root.appendChild(clonedNode);

                        suppXml.appendChild(root);


                        //write out files
                        //At the end, we save the file XML on disk
    //                      TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    //                      Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    //                      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    //                      DOMSource source = new DOMSource(suppXml);
    //                      StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(new File("test_" + i + ".xml"));
    //                      transformer.transform(source, result);

                        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
                        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
                        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(suppXml), new StreamResult(writer));
                        String output = writer.getBuffer().toString().replaceAll("\n|\r", "");

                        System.out.println(output);

                        Message<String> message = new GenericMessage<>(output);
                        this.processor.output().send(message);
                    }

                }
             catch (XPathExpressionException | ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the files are arriving in bursts and because the sink step is sending then to a file with the name being the date time in seconds? More than one xml will end up in the same file if they arrive during the same second?

Comment: I actually solved this a while back but never posted the reply but your answer is correct. I added milliseconds onto the names of my output files and that solved the problem.

Comment: I did something like this.... --name-expression="'FTP_TEST_' + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmssSSS').format(new java.util.Date()) + '.txt'"